# Multithreaded program runs differently depending on the machine

Tags: c++, multithreading

I recently made a multithreaded mandelbrot set generator. I made it on my pc that has an AMD ryzen 3900x, and the more threads i add (way less than the maximum threads of my CPU) the slower it gets.

Then i run the same code on my laptop which has an Intel i7-7700HQ (which is slower and has way less threads), and it run perfectly, and even faster than it did on my desktop pc. what do you guys think is going on?

P.S.

I built the desktop pc, so maybe there could also be some configuration i missed or something like that.

Edit:
here's the code

```
#include <mutex>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include "SDL.h"

#define wid 800
#define hgt 800
#define maxt 8

std::mutex mtx;

long double map(long double x, long double in, long double im, long double on, long double om) { return (x - in) * (om - on) / (im - in) + on; }

void f(SDL_Window *wn, SDL_Renderer *rn, int x, int y, int maxi, long double minx, long double maxx, long double miny, long double maxy) {
    int i = 0;
    long double zr = 0, zi = 0;
    long double cr = map(x, 0, wid, minx, maxx), ci = map(y, 0, hgt, miny, maxy);
    long double rr = 0, ii = 0;
    for (i; i < maxi; i++) {
        rr = zr * zr - zi * zi + cr;
        ii = zr * zi * 2 + ci;
        zr = rr;
        zi = ii;
        if (zr * zr + zi * zi >= 4) break;
    }
    int col = i == maxi ? 0 : (int)map(i, 0, maxi, 0, 255);
    mtx.lock();
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rn, col, col, col, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(rn, x, y);
    mtx.unlock();
}

void fmand(SDL_Window *wn, SDL_Renderer *rn, int maxi, int xn, int xm, long double minx, long double maxx, long double miny, long double maxy) {
    for (int x = xn; x < xm; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < hgt; y++) {
            f(wn, rn, x, y, maxi, minx, maxx, miny, maxy);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long double minx = -2, maxx = 2, zf = 0.96;
    long double miny = -2, maxy = 2;
    long double xoff = 0, yoff = 0;
    int maxi = 256;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *wn = SDL_CreateWindow("Mandelbrot", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, wid, hgt, 0);
    SDL_Renderer *rn = SDL_CreateRenderer(wn, -1, 0);
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rn, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(rn);
    while (1) {
        SDL_RenderPresent(rn);
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT) break;
        if (GetKeyState('Q') & 0x8000) break;
        if (GetKeyState('W') & 0x8000) yoff -= 0.1 * zf;
        if (GetKeyState('S') & 0x8000) yoff += 0.1 * zf;
        if (GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000) xoff -= 0.1 * zf;
        if (GetKeyState('D') & 0x8000) xoff += 0.1 * zf;
        if (GetKeyState('Z') & 0x8000) zf *= 0.7;
        if (GetKeyState('U') & 0x8000) zf /= 0.7;
        if (GetKeyState(VK_OEM_PLUS) & 0x8000) maxi *= 1.2;
        if (GetKeyState(VK_OEM_MINUS) & 0x8000 && maxi > 64) maxi /= 1.2;
        //fmand(wn, rn, maxi, 0, wid, minx * zf + xoff, maxx * zf + xoff, miny * zf + yoff, maxy * zf + yoff);
        std::thread t[maxt];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxt; i++)
            t[i] = std::thread(fmand, wn, rn, maxi, (int)(wid / maxt * i), (int)(wid / maxt * (i+1)), minx * zf + xoff, maxx * zf + xoff, miny * zf + yoff, maxy * zf + yoff);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxt; i++)
            t[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And regarding the compiler i actually use the stardard compiler options that Visual Studio 2019 has, I didn't modify anithing except that i added an -O2 to improve performance.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question, you can only guess. My guess is that you made a mistake somewhere in how you compile, measure or in the code you wrote.

Comment: Maybe the compiler optimized the program for Intel processors which in a subtle way makes it perform bad on AMD...

Comment: @super i added more info in my post. If you need anything else just reply here in the comment.

Comment: @U.W. do you know how to solve the problem? or check if this really is the problem?

Comment: Are you running the program within the IDE? This will be slower than running it independently.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's customary and very common to use all upper-case letters for macros (like `maxt`) so it's easy to differentiate them from variables. At first I thought that `t` was a variable-length array (which isn't allowed in C++). And your names in general doesn't really say much about what the variables or functions are used for. Good naming is hard, but it's also very important, together with good formatting and paragraphs and *comment* to explain to casual readers (like us) what's happening and why you chose one specific solution as opposed to others.

Comment: Now possibly related to your problem: Why do you keep creating and destroying threads in your event loop? This will be done *a lot*. Not to mention that you seem to lock and unlock a mutex for *every* pixel you draw, which add a lot of contention. It seems like your problem is more of a design problem than a code or implementation problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm locking the pixel drawing part because if I don't multiple threads will try to access the same memory address and the program will crash, what do you suggest is better to do? And about the thread loop, I don't really know a better way to do it, I just made that on my own to see if it worked.

Comment: @vll i was running it in IDE on both machines, should i try running the exe itself on them?

Comment: For a window with 800x800 pixels you will be doing that mutext lock/unlock 640000 times *every frame*. For a paltry 10 FPS that means over six million mutex locks/unlocks per second. That is *a lot*. Perhaps you should think about double-buffering, where each thread draws into its own memory buffer, and then at the end you blit all those buffers onto the screen rende?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I could try, where can i learn how to use buffers?